# Why doesn't the below code log "onetwo" as expected?

Tags: javascript

We have the function

```
function Buffer(initValue) {
    this.append(initValue);
}
Buffer.prototype = {
    items: [],
    append: function(str) {
        this.items[this.items.length] = str instanceof Buffer ?       str.toString() : str;
    return this;
},
    toString: function() {
        return this.items.join("");
    }
};
console.log(new Buffer("one").append(new Buffer("two")).toString());
```

but suddenly it logs "onetwoonetwo" - beyond all expectations... Why?

Comment: Your `Buffer.prototype.items` is shared across all instances of `Buffer`.

Comment: the Buffer.prototype.append method is called 3 times: new Buffer("one"), new Buffer("two") and .append(newBuffer("two")). Third time, new Buffer("two") already contains items "one" and "two" so toString will return "onetwo". Prepending "one" and "two" from first 2 calls you will get "onetwoonetwo"

Comment: prototype members are shared as explained by others. What that means and how to use it is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 hope it helps because it is kind of complicated but once you understand it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Several answers explain *why* this happens in your specific instance.

I suspect that what you really want is to let `items` be local to each instance of `Buffer` instead of shared via the prototype. This is simply done by declaring `items = [];` in the constructor:

```
function Buffer(initValue) {
    this.items = []; // This line replaces `items: [],` in the original code.
    this.append(initValue);
}
Buffer.prototype = {
    append: function(str) {
        this.items[this.items.length] = str instanceof Buffer ? str.toString() : str;
        return this;
    },
    toString: function() {
        return this.items.join("");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you applied append multiple time.

Since you are using prototype, your `item` array is shared by your two instance of Buffer.

You should have this: http://jsbin.com/luhoki/3/watch?html,css,js,output

```
function Buffer(initValue) {
    this.append(initValue);
}
Buffer.prototype = {
    items: [],
    append: function(str) {
        this.items[this.items.length] = str instanceof Buffer ?       str.toString() : str;
    return this;
},
    toString: function() {
        return this.items.join("");
    }
};
a = new Buffer("one")
a.append("two")
console.log(a.toString());
// result: "onetwo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is why you get such a behavior.

When following line is encountered

```
console.log(new Buffer("one").append(new Buffer("two")).toString());
```

let's breakdown it in smaller for our convenience.

1. browser evaluates `new Buffer("one")`.
2. then browser evaluates `new Buffer("two")`
3. finally above two results are evalueated like `result1.append(result2)`.

So when first gets evaluated Item array will have one. Then after second will be evaluated then item array will have two element "one" & "two" since it is shared array.

Consider first result as result1 and second result as result2. Now when third step is executed it will join result1's item array which is having two elements and result2's item array which is same as result1's so you get four element in log as onetwoonetwo.